# Why use X and not X<T> for templated constructor and destructor?

Tags: c++, templates

In Professional C++ (2e page 689) it says:

> Only for constructors and the destructor you should use `X` and not
>   `X<T>`.

So:

```
template<typename T>
class X{
    X();                                  // X
    ~X();                                 // X
    X<T>& operator=(const X<T>& rhs);     // X<T>
};
```

Why should you not use `X<T>` for constructor and destructor declarations?

Comment: Both `X` and `X<T>` denote the class `X<T>` inside the class definition. Pick whichever you want, as long as it's `X`.

Comment: @quantdev. Not true. Using T inside the class definition shadows the template parameter class T. I'm not sure what Professional C++ is on about, as T is not needed inside the class definition (X implies X<T> inside the class definition).

Comment: @WernerErasmus What do you mean by *shadow*? `T` will refer to exactly the same class in both cases, won't it?

Comment: @user4815162342 Consider `struct B { typedef int T; }; template <typename T> struct D : B { D() { } ~D() { } };`. Here, `D()` and `~D()` cannot be written as `D<T>()` and `~D<T>()` because the explicit `T` refers to `B::T`.

Comment: @hvd Good example, thanks.

Comment: +1 for question + comment. Is there a way to actually refer to the template T?

Comment: @Serthy Well you could build a type trait that uses partial specialization to deduce it..

Comment: @hvd that is an argument to use `X<T>` in the ctor, so when someone shadows `T` you get a compilation error.

Comment: Or worse, you could get code that compile but does not make what you expect:`D(const D<T> & other);`. You would expect a copy constructor, but what you get is a conversion constructor.

Answer (score 4):

**The quote is, quite simply, *wrong*.**

`X<T>` is the actual name of the type:

> `[C++11: 14.2/6]:` A *simple-template-id* that names a class template specialization is a *class-name* (Clause 9).

…and you can use it everywhere:

```
template<typename T>
class X
{
public:
    X<T>() {}
    ~X<T>() {}
    X<T>& operator=(const X<T>& rhs) {}
};

int main()
{
    X<int> x;
}
```

([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/245cb9ad647016b7))

You may optionally use `X` as a "shorthand", whereby the template argument will be automatically appended for you (kinda):

> `[C++11: 14.6.1/1]:` **Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an *injected-class-name* (Clause 9). The *injected-class-name* can be used as a *template-name* or a *type-name*.** When it is used with a *template-argument-list*, as a *template-argument* for a template *template-parameter*, or as the final identiﬁer in the *elaborated-type-specifier* of a friend class template declaration, it refers to the class template itself. **Otherwise, it is equivalent to the *template-name* followed by the *template-parameters* of the class template enclosed in `<>`.**

…but it's certainly not *required* anywhere.

**It sounds like the author is trying to enforce a *style guide*, but has made it insufficiently clear that it is entirely up to you.**

Comment: The quote doesn't say it is required, and looks like taken out of context. Sounds more like a coding guide line, with which I agree : putting X<T> does look weird, and requires extra typing.

Comment: I would recommend using `X` everywhere as a shorthand, clears up a lot of clutter

Answer (score -1):

Here there is no relevance to X , it is just a class name.

Since constructors and destructors share the same name as the class and there is no return type  for both, there is no need to specify it.